# php: Get maximum cpu usage in last 1 minute?

Tags: php, linux, cpu-usage

The sys_loadavg function in php gives average cpu load values for the last 1 minute, 5 minutes and 15 minutes. However, I am more interested in the peaks in cpu load.

Is there any function which can tell me the max cpu usage in the last 1 minute or 5 minutes. If there are none, which shell_exec command should I go for?

Comment: AFAIK Linux doesn't come with that information, you need to run a tool on the system that gathers and evaluates this information. Since the question is not really about programming you might get better answers on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I found sysstat. This tool is able to monitor a specific process and do a report. If you parse this report you will found your peak. Dunno if this if efficient for your use... See : http://xmodulo.com/2012/08/how-to-measure-average-cpu-utilization.html

Comment: See also this one (always about SysStat), check "1. CPU Usage for All CPU". I think it will help you : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/

Comment: IMO the term **peak usage** has no meaning: given a sufficiently short sampling period it would always be 100% (if you have 1 processor). So the proper answer would be: `function get_peak_usage() return array(100, 100, 100); }`